# looping from early statement

Tags: python, loops, random

I want to make a quiz with random letter of fruit, but the question that I get is always the same. Why is that?

```
import random
from random import shuffle

fruit = ("banana", "apple", "Avocado", "Blackberry", "Coconut", "Durian", "Dragon Fruit", "Eggplant", "Feijoa")

word = random.choice(fruit)
shuffled = list(word)
random.shuffle(shuffled)
shuffled = ''.join(shuffled)

qas = [(shuffled, word),
    (shuffled, word),
    (shuffled, word),
]

for question, rightAnswer in qas:
    answer = raw_input(question + ' ')
    if answer == rightAnswer:
        print 'Right!'
    else:
        print 'No... the answer is ' + rightAnswer
```

Comment: If the script was working right, what would the questions look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you mean that each time you run the program, you get three questions that are the same, in a row.   A different question each time you run the program, repeated three times the same each run.

You should print `qas` after you initialised it, before the loop.

```
qas = [(shuffled, word),
       (shuffled, word),
       (shuffled, word),
]
print qas
```

You will see that you have initialized it with three tuples that are the same.

Why do you think that each element of `qas` would be different?   You put the same thing into them...